# To create a page which checks security zone for various URL's

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I'd like to create a page which checks in background  the security zone like Internet(untrusted) local Intranet (trusted) for various links. I've already written a function which checks the security zone. This works great!:

```
 function isTrustedIE(){
try{
    new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
}
catch(e){
    return false; //untrusted
}

return true; //trusted
}
```

But now I need help for the further action:
I've got the following usecase:
If user call my page it should check a number of URL's whether are trusted or not. 
For Example:
http://www.google.de                       Untrusted (Internet Zone)
http://www.intranet-fh.de                  Trusted (Local Intranet)

Therefore I need a solution in Javascript to load URL's in background without noticing it!
Is this possible?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In the default configuration, this isn't possible.  A page on one domain cannot access a page on another domain due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); you cannot run your code on someone else's domain.

Additionally, I am not aware of an API that allows script access to IE's security zone configuration.

If your page is running in the trusted sites zone, I suppose it may be possible to read the security zone configuration out of the registry via `WScript.Shell`'s `regRead`.  [IE stores the config in HKLM and HKCU under](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569) `\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

Comment: But is it not possible to load URL's in background with a hiding iFrame?

Comment: You can, but you have no access to the content of those iframes if they're hosted on different Origins.